# Converting infix expression to postfix

Tags: assembly, masm

this is an infix expression and I am trying to convert it to postfix.

a + ((b * c) - d) / (e + f)

would this be correct? I am having a bit of trouble with it. Thank you for any help.

my attempt: bc*ad-+ef+/

Comment: Nope. This is not correct.

Comment: I tried over and go something like this: abc*d-ef+/+. I believe I got the first half right but I'm unsure about the back end.

Comment: Yours appears incorrect, I'd say something like: `abc*d-ef+/+`

Comment: you're close, but you missed the () around ((bc*)-d)
so it's abc*d-+ef+/

Comment: hell no. Michael Petch is right it's abc*d-ef+/+, of course the divide is done BEFORE a is added